# Can't parse valid JSON - Unexpected token ( in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm stuck in a problem that doesn't make ANY sense. I'm using the request module to do a request for other server that I own, and this server is clearly answering with the following JSON:

```
{"bucket":"name-of-my-bucket","prefix":"cb012af0-ac7a-414b-b474-a9c71cbec811/"}
```

If I log the type of the response, will be a string:

```
console.log(response.body) // string
```

But I can't parse to a javascript object, because it will throw the following error:

```
Unexpected token ( in JSON at position 0
```

I'm stuck on this for the last 3 hours, I already tried everything, including answering with a empty JSON, but the error persists. Do someone have any idea what it is?

```
const request = require('request-promise');

request.post('http://...', {
  formData: {
    // data here
  }
}).then(response => {
  // request.body is application/json
  console.log(response.body); // {"bucket":"name-of-my-bucket","prefix":"cb012af0-ac7a-414b-b474-a9c71cbec811/"}
  const data = JSON.parse(response.body);
}).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Can you please include the code that does that parsing to the javascript object? Also, are you using ASP.NET? If not, what framework?

Comment: Yes, give me one second.

Comment: Done @Shn_Android_Dev

Comment: If the content type is 'application/json' it's already converted to json object, so you don't need to use JSON.parse()

Comment: Hm. Weird. So, why the response.body is a string?

Comment: @FXux What happens when you call console.log(response.bucket); or console.log(response.prefix); ?

Comment: are you sure the type is string?

can you do this?
eval('myJson='+response.body)

and print consol log value of myJson?

Comment: what if you try `JSON.parse(response.body.toString())`? response.body could be Buffer

Comment: I suggest you try out this API as the documentation is lacking for the `.post()` method ~ https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise#post-data-to-a-json-rest-api

Comment: Just in case, have you checked to see if you are actually calling the right endpoint? I had a similar experience with this exact error message and it turned out that I was requesting data from the wrong api path.

Answer (score 0):

Your json data is in "response" itself.
so console.log(response) prints your json object.